# Convert array to object with similar key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of values as follows

```
[
    {
      "factor": {
        "data": "f1",
        "val": [
          "val1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "factor": {
        "data": "f2",
        "val": [
          "val2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way to convert it to below format

```
{
    "keyvalue": {
        "factor": {
            "data": "f1",
            "val": ["val1"]
        },
        "factor": {
            "data": "f2",
            "val": ["val2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Standard array parsing to object doesn't work in this case given keys has to be unique

Comment: No, an `object` should have unique `key` names!. If you look at the expected `keyvalue` object, you have duplicated `factor` key.

Comment: Perhaps all you want is `const newObj = {keyvalue : obj[0]}` ? Explain your use case since this is an XY Problem

Comment: in this case, which one would you want to get when you do `object.keyvalye.factor` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. Every key in the object has to be unique. To understand this, imagine you have an object with two identical keys:

```js
const obj = {
  "key": 1,
  "key": 2
}
```

But what you should receive when you use an expression like `obj.key`? `1` or `2`? It's nonsense.

You should rethink your object structure, maybe you need an array of objects?

```js
{
  "keyvalue": {
    "factor": [
      {
        "data": "f1",
        "val": ["val1"]
      },
      {
        "data": "f2",
        "val": ["val2"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the `data` field as a key given it's always unique.

Something like this :

```
{
    "factor": {
        "f1": ["val1"],
        "f2": ["val2"]
    }
}
```

Here's how you would proceed to transform the array to the key/value object :

```
let keyValue = {"factor": {}};
theArray.forEach((item) => {
    const key = item.factor.data;
    const value = item.factor.val;
    keyValue.factor[key] = value;
});
```

now the `keyValue` object is as described.